# Short story. Trader in a one man spaceship tries to deliver an elephant at the request of an alien customer

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens

I read it about ten years ago but I think it was written quite a while earlier.

He has a lot of trouble looking after the elephant in zero gravity.

He finally gets to the customer and tells him he has brought a specimen of Earth's largest mammal as requested.

> The customer does not accept the elephant. He had been expecting a blue whale!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Very likely "An Elephant for the Prinkip" by L. J. Stecher, Jr., described in Goodreads as "A fun story about hauling an elephant from earth to a remote planet. As you can imagine there is a lot of detail to deal with. Told in a very fun and light hearted way."  Published in GALAXY, August 1960, where I read it 64 years ago but don't remember any more about it than the Goodreads synopsis.  But here it is:
https://galacticjourney.org/stories/6008galaxyanelephantfortheprinkip.pdf .